# Is ConcurrentSkipListMap put method thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrentskiplistmap

Recently while exploring `ConcurrentSkipListMap` I went through its implementation and found that its put method is not thread-safe. It internally calls `doPut` which actually adds the item. But I found that this method does not use any kind of lock similar to `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Therefore, I want to know whether `add` is thread-safe or not. Looking at the method it seems that it is not thread-safe--that is if this method is executed by two threads simultaneously then a problem may occur.

I know `ConcurrentSkipListMap` internally uses a skiplist data structure but I was expecting `add` method to be thread safe. Am I understanding anything wrong ? Is `ConcurrentSkipListMap` really not thread-safe ?

Comment: The documentation says that it's thread safe. What concrete evidence do you have to the contrary?

Comment: I have checked its implementation i.e. source code of class file ConcurrentSkipListMap.java. As i mentioned the put method internally call doPut method which does not used any kind of lock. You can check the source code of ConcurrentSkipListMap.java

Comment: Using locks is not the only way to achieve thread-safety.  Read on the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, it uses no locks but is completely thread-safe.  You should read up on non-blocking concurrent algorithms, specifically using CAS.

Answer (score 3):

Just because it doesn't use a `Lock` doesn't make it thread unsafe. The [Skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) structure can be implemented [lock free](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=1213189).

You should read the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) carefully.

> ...  Insertion, removal, update, and access **operations safely execute concurrently by multiple threads**. Iterators are weakly consistent, returning elements reflecting the state of the map at some point at or since the creation of the iterator. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException, **and may proceed concurrently** with other operations. ...

Answer (score 2):

The comments in the implementation say:

> Given the use of tree-like index nodes, you might wonder why this
>   doesn't use some kind of search tree instead, which would support
>   somewhat faster search operations. The reason is that there are no
>   known efficient lock-free insertion and deletion algorithms for search
>   trees. The immutability of the "down" links of index nodes (as opposed
>   to mutable "left" fields in true trees) makes this tractable using
>   only CAS operations.

So they use some low level programming features with compare-and-swap operations to make changes to the map atomic. With this they ensure thread safety without the need to synchronize access.

You can read it in more detail in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

We should trust Java API. And this is what java.util.concurrent package docs says:

Concurrent Collections

Besides Queues, this package supplies Collection implementations designed for use in multithreaded contexts: ConcurrentHashMap, `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, ConcurrentSkipListSet, CopyOnWriteArrayList, and CopyOnWriteArraySet.

Comment: @Deepak I must respectfully disagree. Your question was "is it thread safe?" not "how is it thread safe without using locks?"

Comment: @Deepak I mean API says it's thread-safe. As to implementation - I can see that my JRE uses sun.misc.Unsafe.compareAndSwapObject this is probably how they manage to go without locks